# Stored Procedure Renders no Data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

My application consist of a GridView, which contains a **dropdownlist** control and a **textbox** control. What am attempting: when the user selects an item from the dropdownlist, the textbox control will populate with the item description. I'm able to accomplish the task via the following code:

```
Protected Sub ddlStartPartDescrip_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim ddlStartPartDescrip As String = DirectCast(gvPartDetailDescription.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlStartPartDescrip"), DropDownList).Text

        Dim myConnectionStringIII As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ShipperNotificationConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString
        Dim myConnectionIII As New SqlConnection(myConnectionStringIII)
        myConnectionIII.Open()

        Dim mySQLQueryIII As String = "SELECT Part_Name, Part_Desc FROM Part WHERE Part_Name='" + ddlStartPartDescrip.ToString() + "'" + "ORDER BY Part_Name"
        Dim myCommandIII As New SqlCommand(mySQLQueryIII, myConnectionIII)


        Dim myReaderIII As SqlDataReader = myCommandIII.ExecuteReader()

        While (myReaderIII.Read())
            'the orginal code 
            Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
            Dim txtStartPartDescripNum As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtStartPartDescripNum"), TextBox)
            txtStartPartDescripNum.Text = myReaderIII.GetValue(1).ToString
        End While
        myReaderIII.Close()
        myConnectionIII.Close() 
End Sub
```

...however, I'm attempting to accomplish the same task via a **stored procedure**. My problem is, when the list item is selected from the dropdownlist, the textbox control  renders no description.

This is my Stored Procedure:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Part_Name_Descript]
(
    @ddlStartPartDescrip varchar(250)

)
AS
Begin
    SELECT Part_Name, Part_Desc FROM Part WHERE Part_Name='" + @ddlStartPartDescrip + "' 
END
```

This is the code behind, which is placed inside the ddlStartPartDescrip_SelectedIndexChanged as I did with the non-stored procedure approach:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
        'open connection
        con.Open()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Part_Name_Descript", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("@ddlStartPartDescrip", ddlStartPartDescrip)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

        Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While (rd.Read())
            Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
            Dim txtStartPartDescripNum As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtStartPartDescripNum"), TextBox)
            txtStartPartDescripNum.Text = rd.GetValue(1).ToString
        End While

        con.Close()
```

...Could I get some assitance please as to what I'm missing / doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

```
SELECT Part_Name, Part_Desc FROM Part WHERE Part_Name='" + @ddlStartPartDescrip + "'
```

is looking for a `Part_Name` which is the literal string `"@ddlStartPartDescrip"`. You need to use

```
SELECT Part_Name, Part_Desc FROM Part WHERE Part_Name = @ddlStartPartDescrip
```

Edit: incidentally, you already have `Part_Name`, so it may be redundant to select it.